# Boost MPL recursive metafunction definition

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I'm a beginner with MPL so I may well be completely misunderstanding how to use it, but I've tried all I can think of to get this to work.

First, what I'm trying to achieve. I have a bunch of classes of the form:

```
class X
{
  typedef mpl::vector< D1,...,Dn > dependencies;
  ...
}
```

where n can be 0 (no dependencies), and the Di are also classes of the same form. My goal is to define a metafunction

```
template < typename T >
struct unroll_dependencies
{
  typedef ??? type;
}
```

such that 'type' will be an MPL sequence containing T and all of its (recursive) dependencies, with no duplicates and ensuring that any class always comes after its dependencies in the sequence.

My attempt so far is the following (so far I'm ignoring the duplicates issue):

```
template < typename T, typename Enable = void >
struct unroll_dependencies
{
  typedef T t;
  typedef typename t::dependencies t_dep;

  // For each dependency class Di of T, recursively unroll its dependencies
  typedef typename mpl::fold<
    t_dep,
    mpl::vector0<>,
    mpl::lambda<
      mpl::copy<
        typename unroll_dependencies< _2 >::type,  // <-- Compiler error here
        mpl::back_inserter< _1 >
      >
    >
  >::type dep_types;

  // Finally, add T itself after its dependencies
  typedef typename mpl::push_back< dep_types, t >::type type;
};

// Termination case for when a class has no dependencies
template < typename T >
struct unique_dependencies< T, typename boost::enable_if< mpl::empty< typename T::dependencies > >::type >
{
  // A sequence containing T alone
  typedef mpl::vector1< T > type;
};
```

Using VC2012, I get a compiler error on the marked line:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'type'

I don't really understand well how lambdas and placeholders work, but I'm guessing it's something to do with the combination of this with the recursive definition that is causing the problem. Can anyone explain the reason I'm getting this error? Am I going about the solution entirely the wrong way?

Comment: Did you try `boost::mpl::_2` ?